# Adding data to object[][] for JTable object

Tags: java, arrays, swing, object, jtable

I'm new to java and I want to take data that I have stored in a Map and add it to a table.  As I was reading the java tutorials on "How to Use Tables" I found myself lost looking at the sample code below:

```
String[] columnNames = { "blah", "blah" };

Object[][] data = {
{"Kathy", "Smith",
 "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
{"John", "Doe",
 "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
{"Sue", "Black",
 "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
{"Jane", "White",
 "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
{"Joe", "Brown",
 "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
};
```

I'm supposed to then instantiate a JTable object like this:

```
JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

I'm confused as to how I would populate data from a map into an array of objects like they did in the example above?  The data in the rows from my map will be a String and a Float.

Ideally, I would have two columns (just an example), { "File", "Size" } and then my rows would put the string for the file name and the float for size.

I tried various things which I feel are too silly to put here, but nothing worked.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Now I've read a bit further, I'd create a `MapTableModel` for that.  It would accept a `Map` in the constructor.  Column header names would be `Key` and `Value`.  ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks although I don't know how to that, I'm going to read about it and give it a shot.  It sounds like you are definitely leading me into the right direction.

Comment: A Map is not a good idea to store you data when you are using a table. A TableModel needs to be able to access the data by a row/column value. So you would probably be better of to use a DefaultTableModel and copy your data from the map to the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  Object[][] fileList = new Object[fileListVector.size()][2];

for (int i = 0; i < fileListVector.size(); i++) {
    fileList [i][0] = fileListVector.get(i).getFileName();
    fileList [i][1] = fileListVector.get(i).getFileSize();
}
```

You can populate your data from a vector to an array like this.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use a List-based custom TableModel instead.

Have a look at the tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Here's a sample of a List-based read-only TableModel I wrote some time ago:

http://puces-samples.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/puces-samples/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-sample/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/sample/ParticipantTableModel.java?revision=13&view=markup

Instead of the NbBundle you can also use a ResourceBundle, if you're not building your application on top of the NetBeans Platform (though I recommend to use a RCP).